# Need help to find total of specific name in column! (R-Coding)

Tags: r, dplyr

so I'm trying to find the total amount of each class in the Genus column, the following dataframe is shown below:

[Genus/Species Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awWUZ.png)

But it returns values of how many times each Genus is repeating, not it's total amount of the species observed.

I want a dataframe that looks like this:

[Genus - Arachnida
Total Sum - (Total amount of Arachnida)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej01y.png)

Thank you for whoever replies! (This is my first post, English is my second language so hopefully someone understands!)

I've tried using dplyr's function of count like:

BIO205 %>% count(Genus)

But it returns values of how many times each Genus is repeating, not it's total.

Like if I did BIO205 %>% count(Genus), it would return with

[Returning Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js0CI.png)

This is indicating that the word Arachnida is repeating 21 times.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you are trying to sum all the `total` values for each genus. If so `group_by()` is what you want. Here is a reprex:

```
library(dplyr)

data("iris")

iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(sum_col = sum(Sepal.Length))
```

The above code is grouping the data by species, followed by summing all the sepal lengths for each species. In your case, what I would try is the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

BIO205 %>%
    group_by(Genus) %>%
    summarise(sum_col = sum(Total))
```

Hope this helps.